# ps: output modifiers vs output format control

Tags: ps, options

In [the manpage of `ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)

> `-j`     Jobs format.
>
> `-f`     Do full-format listing.
>
> `-o format`
> User-defined format.

```
$ ps -j -o ppid,sid
error: can not use output modifiers with user-defined output

$ ps -f -o ppid,sid
 PPID   SID
 3046 23122
 3046  1002
 1002  1002
 3046 13961
...
```

What does *output modifiers* mean? In the manpage of `ps`, `-j`,`-f` and `-o` are listed under `OUTPUT FORMAT CONTROL`, instead of `OUTPUT MODIFIERS`.

Generally speaking, how are output modifiers used, compared to output format control options?

Are output modifiers options or arguments?

Comment: `-j` asks for output in "jobs format", and `-o ppid,sid` ask for output in "custom format". Which one do you want?

Comment: Their union? why `ps -f -o ppid,sid` works without error?

Comment: Yes, but `-f` has no impact. It should probably give an error too. Though I agree a "union" of formats could have been useful. I'm guessing you want to see `-oppid,pid,pgid,sid,tty,time,cmd`

Comment: Not really. I made up the examples. I want to understand: What does "output modifiers" mean? how are output modifiers used, compared to output format control options? Are output modifiers options or arguments?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a misleading error message.

If you look at the `procps` source, file [`common.h` line 290](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/ps/common.h?view=markup#l290):

```
extern unsigned        format_modifiers; /* -c -j -y -P -L... */
```

`-j` implied `format_modifiers` flag to be set, [which cause the error if used with user defined output](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/ps/sortformat.c?view=markup#l836):

```
if(format_list){
  if(format_flags) return "Conflicting format options.";
  if(format_modifiers) return "Can't use output modifiers with user-defined output";
  if(thread_flags&TF_must_use) return "-L/-T with H/m/-m and -o/-O/o/O is nonsense";
  return NULL;
}
```

A message like *Can't use output **format modifiers** with user-defined output* would be better.

---

FreeBSD `ps` doesn't have this issue, `-j` option cause `ps` to print information about `user, pid, ppid, pgid, sid, jobc, state, tt, time, and command`. Adding `-o` makes the output aggregated:

```
$ ps -j -o ppid,sid
USER     PID PPID PGID  SID JOBC STAT TT     TIME COMMAND          PPID  SID
cuonglm 1196 1195 1196 1196    0 Ss    0  0:00.02 -sh (sh)         1195 1196
cuonglm 1233 1196 1233 1196    1 R+    0  0:00.00 ps -j -o ppid,si 1196 1196
```

---

Output modifiers control *how* information displayed, while output format controls control *what* information displayed.

Example the `s` options is an output format control, because it added process signal information to `ps` output:

```
$ ps s
  UID   PID          PENDING          BLOCKED          IGNORED           CAUGHT STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
 1000 12831 0000000000000000 0000000000000002 0000000000384004 0000000188013003 Ss   pts/1      0:00 zsh
 1000 13067 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000073d3fef9 R+   pts/1      0:00 ps s
```

`f` is an output modifier, because it changed how the output displayed:

```
$ ps f
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
12831 pts/1    Ss     0:00 zsh
13238 pts/1    R+     0:00  \_ ps f
```

Here the output was displayed as hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks. What does "output modifiers" mean? how are output modifiers used, compared to output format control options? Are output modifiers options or arguments?

Comment: Did you read the last part of my answer? What do you mean options and arguments?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your last part. Are output modifiers options or non-option arguments?

Comment: They are both options arguments

Comment: Thanks.  (1) In the manpage of ps, -j means jobs format, and is listed under OUTPUT FORMAT CONTROL, instead of OUTPUT MODIFIERS.  Your reply says that the source code says -j is format modifier. Is -j jobs format or format modifier? (2) -f is also listed under output format control in ps manpage. Why -f can work with -o, while -j can't?

Comment: @Tim: I think it's just a missing in documentation. Also note that the *format modifiers* in source code is different with `output modifiers* in documentation. AFAICT, *format modifiers* means *modify* the format of output, why *output modifiers* means modify *how* to display the output. That's why there're some *format modifiers* you can mix with user-defined, others can't.

Comment: format modifiers means modify the format of output, and output format controls control what information displayed. Are format modifiers also output format controls?

Comment: @Tim: As the source code implied, it's a subset of output format controls.