# ps: error: conflicting format options

Tags: ps, options

```
$ ps  -l -o ruid,euid,rgid,egid,sess -p $$ 
error: conflicting format options

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).


$ ps  -F -o ruid,euid,rgid,egid,sess -p $$ 
error: conflicting format options

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details 

$ ps  -w -o ruid,euid,rgid,egid,sess -p $$ 
 RUID  EUID  RGID  EGID  SESS
 1000  1000  1000  1000  5678
```

I was wondering what format options conflict with each other?

How should I avoid such error?

Why does the third command succeed without the same error?

I just would like to show more information for the current process, so I used `-Fl` together with some fields specified via `-o`.

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/266229/237982

Answer (score 4):

This isn’t clear from the documentation, but `-o` conflicts with most other format specifiers, *i.e.* options which determine which columns are selected for output (in Unix style, `-F`, `-j`, `-l`; however `-f` and `-M`, which *add* columns to the selection, don’t conflict with `-o`). I imagine the reasoning is that if you’re specifying the list of columns explicitly, you can’t also use a pre-defined format.

`-w` works with `-o` because it’s not a format control, it’s an output control: it modifies the output of any selected columns.

You might find `-O` useful: it behaves like `-o`, but adds a few pre-defined columns (process identifier, state, TTY, execution time, and command line).