# How do ` -f` and `-o` interact in `ps`?

Tags: ps

How do `-f` and `-o` interact in `ps`?
They shouldn't work together, according to [ps: output modifiers vs output format control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266229/ps-output-modifiers-vs-output-format-control)  and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446198/674, since `-f` implicitly specifies the fields, while `-o` allows user to specify the fields.

`man ps` says

> ```
> -f     Do full-format listing. This option can be combined with many other UNIX-style options to add additional columns.  It also causes the command arguments to be
>           printed.  When used with -L, the NLWP (number of threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be added.  See the c option, the format keyword args, and the format
>           keyword comm.
>
> f      ASCII art process hierarchy (forest).
> ```

They seem to be unrelated options/arguments.

But why

1. `ps -f -o cmd` works just like `ps f`, showing the parent-child relation?
2. `ps -f -o ...` select the same number of processes as `ps f`?

   ```
   $ ps f  | wc -l
   224
   $ ps -f -o pid |  wc -l
   224
   ```
3. `ps -f` selects different processes with and without `-o`?

   ```
   $ ps -f  |  wc -l
   5
   ```
4. `-e` seems not work here?

   ```
   $ ps -e -f -o pid,ppid,comm |  wc -l
   224

   $ ps -e -f  |  wc -l
   414

   $ ps -e  -o pid,ppid,comm |  wc -l
   414
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `ps` in a lot of Gnu/Linuxes has compatibility with at least two versions of `ps`: from system V and BSD. Some options are from one, and some from the other.

Comment: I can't get my head around the manual, and just use the same few options. If anyone can reference a better manual, then +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

**1. and 2.:**

Yes, `ps -f -o ...` works just like `ps f`, because `ps -f -o ...` outputs the same as `ps f -o ...` which is the output as process hierarchy.

Example:

```
ps -f -o user,pid,ppid,cmd
# is the same as
ps f -o user,pid,ppid,cmd
```

**3.**

`ps -f` seems to select all processes of your current shell (tty) while while `ps -f -o ...` outputs the processes of all ttys.

Example:

```
ps -f
# selects the same processes of current tty as
ps -o user,pid,ppid,cmd,tty

# and... have a look at the tty value here
ps -f -o user,pid,ppid,cmd,tty
```

**4.**

Yes, `ps -ef` doesn't seem to work with `-o`. You can add `-H` for a hierarchy like in `ps -eH -o user,pid,ppid,cmd`.